# Eccentricity of vertex in a permutation cycle graph

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, permutations, cyclic-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

The permutation cycle graph is defined as follows.

> **Permutation Cycle Graph**: A permutation cycle graph for a given
>   permutation $\pi$ of a finite set $V$, is its cycle graph $\Gamma$
>   such that the vertex set is $V$ and the edges are pairs $\left(\mu,
>  \omega\right)$ for which $\pi(\mu)=\omega$.

In that case for any $\pi$ with more than one cycle, the graph is the disjoint union of at least two cycles. So, the eccentricity any vertex is infinite.

Am I getting it right?

Comment: Is eccentricity even defined for graphs which are not strongly connected?